# JSP couldnt link css files and js files

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp

I am new to jsp. I am using Glassfish server from netbeans. Problem is that i could link my jsp file with css and javascripts. Here's the format of my file structure

```
Web Pages  
 --Web-Inf  
 --assets  
    --css   
     --style.css  
  --js  
 --jquery.js  
 --includes    
--header.jsp  
--footer.jsp  
--sidebar.jsp  
 --pages    
--home.jsp  
 --index.jsp
```

Here's the code in my index.jsp

```
<%@include file="includes/header.jsp" %>

<%
    if (request.getParameter("page") == null) {
        %>
        <%@include file="pages/home.jsp" %>
        <%
    } else {
        %>

        <%
    }
%>

    <%@include file="includes/sidebar.jsp" %>
</div>

<!--Latest end-->

<%@include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

And here's my code in header.jsp

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Are you getting `404` error on loading the css. Is that inside `web-inf`?

Comment: @SanKrish yes i am getting 404 error and the css folder is outside the web-inf

Comment: What is the url you are using to accessing the application?

Comment: @sadasidha it is http://localhost:8080/pricingsystem/

Comment: The directory name should be "Web Pages" rather "Web-Pages" that is no '-' in the name.

Comment: @sadasidha yes it is Web Pages

Comment: @ShreerajKarki when your index.jsp is in already folder it means that your application is already pointing to the includes. Hence you can just give as `<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>` try this out

Comment: @Naveen nope my index.jsp is not in the folder and i am not reffering to footer.jsp. Problem is i am not being able to link css files and javascript files.

Comment: @ShreerajKarki Your header and footer are working fine only prob is with the JS and CSS, try  giving `../` before passing the string in `href`

Comment: @Naveen still not working :(

Comment: Did you try <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" ... ?

Comment: nope anyhow this worked for me
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative urls to index.jsp

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```